# Wordpress wrong image path

Tags: wordpress, image-uploading

i have a problem with one of my wordpress installations.
In the Wordpress Media Library all my pictures are shown like this:
[image]

while on "edit image", they are shown normal. I also checked the path and it is correct. I already tried to fix it with the user rights but still no solution... 
[image]

but this isn't the only problem. The imageuploader starts to generate tons of thumbnail sizes, while my site has no thumbnail settings in the function.php/wp-config.php [image]

Any help? I really don't have a glue what to do next...

Greetings

Phil

Answer (score 0):

LinkChecker is a good little plugin that gives a decent amount of details.  It might help to make sure that the image url is pointing to the right place....(typos are a pita).

But as a test, why not try setting the folder to 777?  Also, who is the owner of that folder?  If WP does not have ownership rights, it will fail to get the image.